# Java log request with corresponding response

Tags: java, web-services, logging

I have web application which interacts with SOAP and REST external web services for some use cases as a client, and as a server for other use cases.
By the business requirements I need to log all outcoming requests to the external systems with the corresponding response, and I also need to log all incoming requests with the corresponding response.
So i need to write the list of objects like this:
{communicationId, timestamp, OUT[IN], request, response}.

What is the best way to achieve it from several perspectives:
1. To have the code in the single place if it is possible.
2. To map request with corresponding response effectively.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is dependent on the tooling you are using.

I assume you have an ESB (such as [Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/)) in front of your web application. If so, you have the ESB log the necessary information on the way in/out of the app.

If you have Apache CXF available, you could use [interceptors](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) to do the logging for you.

As for logging the 'response' - does this mean the actual object? If so, you could use JAXB to convert to XML and then log.